# C# DateTime conversion when time changes from winter to summer time

Tags: c#

I am getting this error:

> The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time.  For example, when
> the clock is adjusted forward, any time in the period that is skipped
> is invalid

when I try to convert time 2020-03-29 02:30 from Eastern European Time (GMT+2) to UTC time.

According to [this site](http://timein.org/dst/finland/) the clock should change at 03:00 for Finland, which means that time 02:30 should be possible to convert to UTC.

But when I run the following code, an exception is thrown.

```
var timezoneMap = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);
var timezoneInfo = timezoneMap["E. Europe Standard Time"]; 

var localTime1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(2020, 12, 15, 0, 0, 0), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var localTime2 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

var utc1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime1, timezoneInfo); // 2020-12-14 22:00 correct
var utc2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime2, timezoneInfo); // throws exception
```

What is wrong with the second conversion, why is there an exception?

Comment: Those are unknown, not local DateTime values. In any case, if you care about offsets you should use DateTimeOffset

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [If inputDt.Kind is DateTimeKind.Unspecified, the conversion is performed as if inputDt was local time.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site you're looking at uses the [IANA time zone data](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which I believe to be accurate.

But your code uses the *Windows* time zone database, which in this case looks like it has a discrepancy... it seems to think that the transition is at midnight UTC rather than 1am UTC. Here's code to demonstrate that:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Europe Standard Time");

        // Start at 2020-03-28T23:00Z - definitely before the transition
        var utc = new DateTime(2020, 3, 28, 23, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            var local = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, zone);
            Console.WriteLine($"{utc:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} UTC => {local:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} local");
            utc = utc.AddMinutes(30);
        }
    }
}
```

Output (annotated):

```
2020-03-28 23:00 UTC => 2020-03-29 01:00 local
2020-03-28 23:30 UTC => 2020-03-29 01:30 local
2020-03-29 00:00 UTC => 2020-03-29 03:00 local  <= Note the change here, at midnight UTC
2020-03-29 00:30 UTC => 2020-03-29 03:30 local
2020-03-29 01:00 UTC => 2020-03-29 04:00 local
2020-03-29 01:30 UTC => 2020-03-29 04:30 local
2020-03-29 02:00 UTC => 2020-03-29 05:00 local
2020-03-29 02:30 UTC => 2020-03-29 05:30 local
```

The current IANA data definitely *does* say 1am UTC, as shown in [this line of the rules](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/316c1598e166e15c27fe611cacd81aeada2a836d/europe#L574). So I believe the web site is correctly interpreting the data, and it's just a matter of the Windows time zone database being "different" (and, I suspect, incorrect).